# Converting multivalued column in table A to multiple rows in table B Mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Given 2 tables, I want to convert the multivalued row in table 1

Given 2 tables
Table A

```
id  value
ae  [1,2,4,5]
ac  [1,6]
```

Table B

```
id  value
ae   1
ae   2
ae   4
ae   5
ac   1
ac   6
```

I know I have to insert a before insert trigger on table B, but I cannot figure out the logic.

Comment: have you mysql 8? then look for json_table, eslse you can look for splittng stings

Comment: What is the datatype for column `value` in table A? and what is MySQL version?

Comment: mysql8, value is varchar

Answer (score 1):

Another way to convert JSON arrays in MySQL into rows (I assume "value" column in table A is json array type). Transform Table A into Table B.

MySql >= 8.0:

First with a recursive query I get json array indexes for each json array with a length > 0 (a row per index), then I join table A with indexes query and used JSON_EXTRACT() to extract each json array value in a row.

```
WITH RECURSIVE indexes AS (SELECT id, 0 AS json_index FROM A WHERE JSON_LENGTH(value) > 0
                          
                        UNION ALL
                        
                        SELECT i.id, i.json_index + 1
                        FROM indexes i
                        INNER JOIN A ON A.id = i.id AND i.json_index < JSON_LENGTH(A.value) - 1
                        )
                        
SELECT A.id, JSON_EXTRACT(A.value, CONCAT('$[', i.json_index, ']')) AS arrayValue
FROM A
INNER JOIN indexes i ON A.id = i.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

Get the total of value need to be separated using `LENGTH()`:

Take the first example `[1,2,4,5]`. There are 4 values separated by commas here. If we do `LENGTH(value)`, we will get `9` as there are 9 characters including `[` and `,`. Then we do `LENGTH(REPLACE(value,',',''))` which we replace the commas from the values with nothing and this will give us `6`. If we subtract them, we'll get `3` which we suppose to get `4` so we add `+1` in the final calculation. We end up with something like this:

```
(LENGTH(value)-LENGTH(REPLACE(value, ',', '' )))+1
```

With that, you'll get `ae` with `4` and `ac` with `2`. From here there are three usage of this information:

1. To make a numbering sequence referring to the largest number we get, in this case `4`.
2. To return repeated row based on how many length the `value` column has.
3. To be used in `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function and return the value accordingly.

In the end, I've managed to create two queries using the same idea but for a different MySQL version.

For older MySQL version (before v8), this might do:

```
SELECT id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val,',',ln),',',-1) AS value
 FROM
(SELECT 1 AS ln UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) RN
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT id, 
        REPLACE(REPLACE(value,'[',''),']','') AS val 
   FROM tableA) A
ON ln<=(LENGTH(val)-LENGTH(REPLACE(val,',','')))+1
ORDER BY id, value;
```

However, the issue here is that the hardcoded numbering sequence by rows on this part of the query `..(SELECT 1 AS ln UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) RN..`. Meaning that if there's a `value` where the length is everchanging, then this part need to be constantly edited.

For MySQL v8 (but not quite v8.0.4 that supports `JSON_TABLE`):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT 1 AS ln, MAX((length(value)-length(replace(value,',','')))+1) AS totval
from tableA UNION ALL
SELECT ln+1, totval FROM cte WHERE ln+1 <= totval)
SELECT id, 
       REGEXP_REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value,',',ln),',',-1),'[^0-9]','') AS value
FROM cte 
LEFT JOIN tableA
ON ln<=(length(value)-length(replace(value,',','')))+1
ORDER BY id, value;
```

Here I'm using `WITH RECURSIVE` function to dynamically generate the numbering sequence, which means that if the length is more than 4, there's no need to edit the query.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8fddec46bccc27fd239bda7f37b87942)